# Remove first element when sep is >

Tags: r

I have a character variable

```
   d > r > t > a > t > r > f
```

And want to remove the first element (in this case d) from this selection. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Is it a single string, e.g. `var <- "d > r > t > a > t > r > f"`, or multiple, e.g. `var <- c("d", "r", …)`

Comment: Multiple it is in a character variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `substring`

```r
a <- substring(a, 2)
# [1] " > r > t > a > t > r > f"
```

## Data

```r
a <- "d > r > t > a > t > r > f"
```

See `?substring` for more information.

Comment: Provided OP is after a single string, using substr is by far the fastest solution, as there's no need for splitting/parsing of the string. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

In case the length of the characters between `>` can be variable,

```
z = "d > r > t > a > t > r > f"
> paste(strsplit(z," > ")[[1]][-1],collapse= " > ")
[1] "r > t > a > t > r > f"

z2 = "dew > rd > tewa > adf > ta > eer > ff"
> paste(strsplit(z2," > ")[[1]][-1],collapse= " > ")
[1] "rd > tewa > adf > ta > eer > ff"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` with a `regex` *to remove first element when sep is >* and keeping the rest as it is:

```
sub(".+?> ", "", "d > r > t > a > t > r > f")
#[1] "r > t > a > t > r > f"
```

or you can use `read.table` and remove the first one with subseting using `[-1]` and split it using the separator `>` like:

```
read.table(sep=">", text="d > r > t > a > t > r > f")[-1]
#   V2  V3  V4  V5  V6 V7
#1  r   t   a   t   r   f
```

or using `strsplit` and `trimws`:

```
trimws(strsplit("d > r > t > a > t > r > f", ">")[[1]][-1])
#[1] "r" "t" "a" "t" "r" "f"
```

Comment: Depending on OPs output, you will probably need a `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` inside `read.table` when concatenating entries into a single string with `paste`.

Answer (score 0):

Assumming you mean a character vector like `vec <- c("d", "r", "t", "a", "t", "r", "f")`, then just use `vec[-1]` to remove the first element:

```r
vec <- c("d", "r", "t", "a", "t", "r", "f")
vec[-1]

# [1] "r" "t" "a" "t" "r" "f"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a <- "d > r > t > a > t > r > f"
substr(r,unlist(gregexpr("[A-z]+\\s*?>\\s*?",r))[2],nchar(r))
```

Comment: An alternative `substr(a,3,nchar(a))`.